# WHERE does 19.10 store its wallpapers?

Tags: ubuntu, wallpaper

My Ubuntu has a bunch of garbage wallpapers that I don't like, where does 19.10 store its wallpapers so I can delete theirs and add a bunch of my own??

I've tried using 'find' to find all folders named wallpapers, no joy.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to do what I wanted was to install Variety, very handy tool.